# Positioning with Canvas

Tags: html, css, canvas, position

I'm trying to make a layout like on the picture but I'm struggling with canvas positioning. How can I put h1 forward?
Also, whats better for the black and white skewed rectangles? To do them with CSS or another Canvas on top of the first one?
Also I would appreciate some advice on responsiveness of this layout.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background-color: #181818;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
p{
  color: #f0f0f0;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 10em;
}
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 40px 0px;
  color: #f0f0f0;
}

td{
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
canvas{
  width:100%; height:100%;
  position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, red, #380000);
  z-index: 0;
}
.homepage .portfolioPage{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* .mainWrapper {
  position: relative;

} */


.mainPage{
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  align-content: center;

}
.rightbox{
padding: 0 40%;
width: 600px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Font -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand:wght@700&family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title> </title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="mainWrapper">
    <canvas id="#particles-js" width="1000" height="500"></canvas>

      <!-- Homepage -->
      <div class='homepage'>

        <table style="width:100%">
          <tr>
            <!-- Left Side -->
            <td>
              <div class='mainPage'>
                <div class="blk-box">
                  <div class="block">
                    <h1>Barqawi</h1>
                  </div>
                  <div class="block">
                    <h1>Maroun</h1>
                  </div>
                  <div class="block">
                    <h1>Grey</h1>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <!-- Right Side -->
            <td>
              <div class='mainPage'>
                <div class="rightbox">
                  <p id="jrdev">Jr Software Developer</p>
                  <div class="portfolioBtn">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>


      </div>


  </div>
</body>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The tag

```
<h1>
```

is normally reserved for SEO keywords. Anyway, you can do the following:

```
.block { transform: skewX(-10deg);}
```

If you don't want the text to be skewed along, you should define another element outside to contain the text and then use negative margin or absolute positioning to fix the position of the text.

As for mobile reponsiveness, I would advise converting all absolute lengths to relative lengths, eg. 100%, 100vh, 100vw etc.

You can also use media queries to specify separate layouts for portrait and landscape orientations:

```
@media only screen and (orientation: portrait) {
  body {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
@media only screen and (orientation: landscape) {
  body {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out. Just in case someone need it, here is the code.

```
canvas {
 width:100%; height:50%;
 top:0px; left:0px;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, red, #380000);
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -1;
}

.mainWrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.homepage {
  position: relative;
}
```